# Move elements to the right Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, sorting

I have an array with 5 values. I want to cycle through the array so that the values index all increase by one and the item in the final position moves to the front of the array. So for example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Would become:

```
[5,1,2,3,4]
```

In python it is as simple as this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst = lst[-1] + lst[:-1]
```

However I am not able to figure out how to do this in javascript

What is the correct syntax for performing this in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) to get the last entry from the array, and [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to push it on the front:

```
array.unshift(array.pop());
```

Live Example:

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log("before", array);
array.unshift(array.pop());
console.log("after", array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Going the other way, [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) shifts the array over and gives you the first entry, and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds to the end.

```
array.push(array.shift());
```

Live Example:

```js
const array = [5,1,2,3,4];
console.log("before", array);
array.push(array.shift());
console.log("after", array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Comment: And if i wanted to do the reverse? (move elements to the left?)

Comment: @Maurio - [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) shifts the array over and gives you the first entry, and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds to the end.

Comment: @Maurio array.push(array.shift());

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be like this:

```js
const test = [1,2,3,4,5];

test.unshift(test.pop());

console.log(test)
```

Comment: Or just use the return value of `pop`.